# Old movie involving unexplained handprint on mirror in spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I would like the title of an old black-and-white movie. My best guess is that it would have been released in the 1950s or early 1960s, as I saw at least a small part of it when I was about ten years old (1964).

It was a live-action film in English, presumably American or British in origin, but it could have been dubbed.

The only thing that I remember about the film is that (I *think*) the setting is a spaceship (flying somewhere in outer space) that is supposed to have only one man aboard, but in one scene, the man goes into an area of the spaceship where there is a mirror, and on the mirror there is a hand print. That hand print, of course, is not his own, i.e., he is evidently being served notice that he is not alone on the ship after all...

Shortly after I saw this scene, the horn of the '63 station wagon (precursor to the soccer-mothership SUV) sounded out in the driveway, summoning me to baseball practice with my junior cronies, so I had to bail on this movie and I never again encountered it. So I don't know just what dynamic might have played out after the mysterious appearance of the hand print: was it all in the astronaut's mind, or was the print placed there pre-takeoff by a cold-war enemy, to drive the astronaut nuts, or was there really someone else on board, and if so, who and why? That is why I would appreciate any help with identifying this film.

Sorry to be able to provide so little info. Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Sounds like an awesome premise for a sci fi psychological/horror movie.

Comment: The only image of a handprint in a glass in a spaceship that comes to my mind belongs to Ark (2009). A canceled TV series (only one episode) from director Trey Strokes. I could be a coincidence or possibly inspired by your movie. 
https://imgur.com/a/PEVjPKk